# blank page when using pushasync xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

how are you?

I created a top ContentPage class inheriting a ZXingScannerPage class to be able to create methods in order to better streamline the code. And in it a method that takes as a parameter a Label and a ContentPage to set the data read by the Scanner.

```
       public String ScannResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class ScannerHelper : ZXingScannerPage
    {
        public  ScannerHelper() 
        {
            this.OnScanResult += (result) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send( new Message { ScannResult = result.Text }, "ScannResult");
                // Parar de escanear
                this.IsScanning = false;

                // Alert com o código escaneado
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    DisplayAlert("Código escaneado", result.Text, "OK");
                    Navigation.PopAsync(false);
                });
            };
        }

        public static void teste(Label label, ContentPage contentPage)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Message>(contentPage, "ScannResult", message => {
                label.Text = message.ScannResult;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So far everything is working, but when I call this class on a button and run it later, the screen takes the data and goes to the label, but when going to another page with a PushAsync the page is blank and if I go back to the pages and try to go to the next one it is blank and the strangest thing if I leave the app on my cell phone going to the menu and returning to it the page is normal. Example: Page A calls the Scanner and works, on Page A I go to Page B and it is blank, I go back to Page A and I go back to the page before Page A and then I go back to A to A and now it is in White.

Example of how I use the Methods on the buttons and on the page:

```
{
            InitializeComponent();
            ScannerHelper.teste(lblNomeProduto, this);
        }

        private void ButtonScanner(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannerHelper());
        }
```

Comment: Does the App have permission to use the camera?

Comment: Yes he have, and the android code have all permission and configurations to work